# Match an element only when it appears in the right half of the parsing string

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, pyparsing

#### The problem

I want to create a parser which matches strings like

```
"alpha beta 123 cpart"

 ----^----- -^- --^--
     A:      B:   C:
 alphanums  num alpha
```

However the **B** part should only match when it appears in the second half of the string (i.e. to the 'right' of the string's mid-point).

So the above sample string should be parsed into the parts:

```
A: ['alpha', 'beta']
B: '123'
C: ['cpart']
```

But the string `"123 alpha beta cpart"` should be parsed into:

```
A: '123 alpha beta cpart'
B: ''
C: ''
```

#### First approximation with pyparsing

As a starting point with [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) I tried to use the `matchOnlyAtCol` function (thinking I could later provide a modified version which accepts a range instead of a single column). However I got stuck on some strange behaviour of `matchOnlyAtCol`. Here my demo code:

```
b_only_near_end = pp.Word(pp.nums)\
                    .setParseAction(pp.matchOnlyAtCol(12))('B')
a = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphanums), stopOn=b_only_near_end)('A')
c = pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas))('C')
expr = a + pp.Optional(b_only_near_end) + c
```

**1)** When I feed the first sample string `"alpha beta 123 cpart"` into `expr`'s `ParseString` I get the expected result

```
A: ['alpha', 'beta']
B: '123'
C: ['cpart']
```

because **B** starts exactly on column 12.

**2)** When I feed it the second string `"123 alpha beta cpart"` (part **B** on column 1) I get

```
ParseException:
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
">!<123 alpha beta cpart"
```

Why? `b_only_near_end` should not match at all and therefore not stop the expression `a`, so I expect that `a` eats up all characters and I don't expect an exception to bubble up, because all parts are somehow optional (either via the `Optional` class or via the `ZeroOrMore` construct).

---

#### Update: What match debugging reveals

I switched  on debugging via `setDebug()` for the `ZeroOrMore` elements via the following expression code:

```
b_word = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName('_B_word_')
b_word.setDebug()
b_only_near_end = b_word\
                    .setParseAction(pp.matchOnlyAtCol(12))('B')
a_word = pp.Word(pp.alphanums).setName('_A_word_')
a_word.setDebug()
a = pp.ZeroOrMore(a_word, stopOn=b_only_near_end).setName('__A__')('A')
a.setDebug()

c_word = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setName('_C_word_')
c_word.setDebug()
c = pp.ZeroOrMore(c_word).setName('__C__')('C')
c.setDebug()

expr = a + pp.Optional(b_only_near_end) + c
```

**1)** When feeding in the string `"alpha beta 123 cpart"` I get as debug output:

```
Match __A__ at loc 0(1,1)
Match _B_word_ at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected _B_word_ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match _A_word_ at loc 0(1,1)
Matched _A_word_ -> ['alpha']
Match _B_word_ at loc 5(1,6)
Exception raised:Expected _B_word_ (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)
Match _A_word_ at loc 5(1,6)
Matched _A_word_ -> ['beta']
Match _B_word_ at loc 10(1,11)
Matched _B_word_ -> ['123']
Matched __A__ -> ['alpha', 'beta']
Match _B_word_ at loc 11(1,12)
Matched _B_word_ -> ['123']
Match __C__ at loc 14(1,15)
Match _C_word_ at loc 15(1,16)
Matched _C_word_ -> ['cpart']
Match _C_word_ at loc 20(1,21)
Exception raised:Expected _C_word_ (at char 20), (line:1, col:21)
Matched __C__ -> ['cpart']
```

**2)** With the string `"123 alpha beta cpart"` the output is:

```
Match __A__ at loc 0(1,1)
Match _B_word_ at loc 0(1,1)
Matched _B_word_ -> ['123']
Matched __A__ -> []
Match _B_word_ at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:matched token not at column 12 (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match __C__ at loc 0(1,1)
Match _C_word_ at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected _C_word_ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Matched __C__ -> []
```

plus the ParseException:

```
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
">!<123 alpha beta cpart"
```

So this means part **A** matches the beginning of the string - with empty match result, because `a_word` does not match - So I guess I have to make **A** more greedy, but how?

The strange thing is that

```
Matched __A__ -> []
```

occurs before

```
Match _B_word_ at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:matched token not at column 12 (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

**A** should "wait" with the match result longer, but how can i force it to do so?

Maybe the whole approach is not fruitful? Is there another way to achieve matching only in the second part of a string?

Comment: Try attaching '.setDebug()' to some of your repeated Word expressions and see what kind of debug output you get.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Just added the debug output to the question: In the problem case **A** matches, but very strangely it matches the empty string, not the full string.

Comment: Add .setDebug to the Word expression inside the ZeroOrMore of a, and anyplace else you think might help you see what is happening inside pyparsing.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Added more debugging...

Comment: @PaulMcGuire added debugging for `b_word`. This brings us closer: Strangely **A** is matched (as empty) *before* the `b` colum test gets executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the code of **First approximation with pyparsing** look at the line

```
b_only_near_end = pp.Word(pp.nums)\
                  .setParseAction(pp.matchOnlyAtCol(12))('B')
```

When attaching the parse action, set the `callDuringTry` option:

```
b_only_near_end = pp.Word(pp.nums)\
                  .setParseAction(pp.matchOnlyAtCol(12), 
                                  callDuringTry=True))('B')
```

Then `matchOnlyAtCol` will be checked "during lookaheads and alternate testing" (quoted [from the docu](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setParseAction)) as well. ***Without the option this does not happen!***

2) In order to address the title question "*Match an element only when it appears in the right half of the parsing string*" (spelt out under **The Problem**) define a function:

```
def matchOnlyInRightHalf():
    """
    Helper method for defining parse actions that require matching in the
    right half of the parse string.
    """
    def verifyInRightHalf(strg,locn,toks):
        col = pp.col(locn,strg)
        middle = len(strg) // 2
        if not (col> middle):
            raise pp.ParseException(strg, locn,
                                "matched token not in right half of string")
    return verifyInRightHalf
```

and use it as the parse action:

```
b_only_near_end = b_word.setParseAction(matchOnlyInRightHalf(),
                                        callDuringTry=True)
```

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Finally I found the `callDuringTry` option! :-)